# upgrade android.arch.persistence.room version error on build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-room

I'm trying to upgrade android.arch.persistence.room in my android project.

Now I'm using the alpha-9 and all is working correctly. 
If I try to use the "released" version 1.0.0 I'll recive the error reported below on the line *compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'*.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

The gradle file is

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
}
```

Does someone kwnow how I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the changes to following versions would work for you:

```
(archLifecycleVersion = '1.0.0'
roomLifecycleVersion = '1.0.0')



annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.ext.archLifecycleVersion"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$rootProject.ext.archLifecycleVersion"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.ext.archLifecycleVersion"

compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomLifecycleVersion"
```